# How can I increase my productivity through my daily habits?

Tags: productivity

I recently posted this similar question [here](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/8550/7975) but I guess even this site could help me with that it or could even be better.

I am student how can I increase my productivity for studies by adapting/incorporating some habits into my lifestyle that will help me in the long run.

It got me curious because my teacher's keep telling me but getting a goods score, it's not all about studies , but other practices /habit that help too. I think what he means is  more on the line of smart work v/s hard work. And the earlier you'll incorporate them in your life , the more/better results one can see.

So what I want to ask is that are there few practices taht I can incorporate in my life that will help me in my studies in the long run or can be beneficial for me, both physically and mentally.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been posted on another SE site already https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/8550/how-can-i-use-music-to-increase-productivity

Comment: @RichardErickson Is this practice something that I should not do... ?? Should I delete the question from one of the sites ?? I thought of asking the question here too , because not all of the users use all the sites and I thought certain users from both the sites can help me / find it useful.

Comment: This Stack Exchange [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) says **no** to cross-posting. I would leave the question you think is the best site. If you cannot decide which site to you, ask on SE meta or the meta for a specific site.

Comment: @RichardErickson I have edited the question...

Comment: It seems sufficiently different now, that I'd leave it live.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, my advice would be quite different from "work smart", though there are aspects of that also.

Get enough sleep. Every day. If you have exams, don't "cram" for them or stay up too late. Make sure you work steadily enough so that cramming isn't necessary and a brief review of essentials is all that is required. Just review your notes (and summaries).

Get enough exercise. Every day. Part of it is aerobic if possible, though just walking can also be a benefit. The time it takes for this isn't "wasted" as it lets your mind integrate the things you are learning.

Eat healthy and on a regular schedule. Avoid high caffeine and high sugar snacks. Or, limit them, at least. Avoid fad diets for balanced diets with fruit and veggies included.

Engage socially with people, face to face. At least a bit. Don't close yourself off.

Generally, watch your health and deal promptly with any issues. Don't neglect mental health.

As for the "work smart" part:

Take a lot of notes. Summarize those notes. Paper is known to be better than electronic (yes, there is research) as it engages your mind more completely.

Do a lot of reinforcement, such as by doing a lot exercises in your courses. Get a lot of feedback on what you do and what you write. Strongly prefer working on exercises over looking at solutions.

Ask for help when you need it, but try to answer your own questions first so you can respond intelligently to "What have you tried?".

Don't let social media dominate your life. Step away from the keyboard.

Have a schedule for work and play. It can be flexible, but stick to it unless there is a sufficient reason to deviate.

Comment: Generally I would also suggest to work in groups as this "forces" one to engage in social groups and gives a bit of routine into learning. Even if learning in a group has more opportunities for off-topic conversations, from experience, the overall productivity is higher as you motivate each other and it's not as exhausting as sitting alone on a table all day.